# uncomfortable mix of server and client code - how can I achieve both of these requirements

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am working with a repeater control - each item on the repeater gets an image & a link button.

From a functionality side of things, clicking the link button fires an itemcommand (supplying a commandargument as it goes). This item command then runs some serverside code to populate another repeater with data related to the first repeater as a sublist.

From a UI side of things, each item on the repeater has its image opacity reduced right down with exception of the clicked link buttons image.

This is where I run in to trouble:

```
$('.showSubCats').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
                $(".myImages").animate({ opacity: 0.2 }, 300);
                $(this).parent().children('img').animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 300);

});
```

This shows the current clicked image and hides the rest brilliantly.. BUT I had to introduce e.preventdefault() as the postback on itemcommand was obviously undoing the work jquery had just done to the images.

By introducing .preventdefault(), I have now lost the itemcommand as it is prevented. argh.

thought I have had:

- I tried to run a bit of jquery from code behind using registerstartupscript, but it ran before the DOM had completed and my images reverted back to 1.0 opacity
- I tried an ajax call in my jquery to run the serverside script that way - but I couldn't get a workable solution on that
- I tried adding {return: true};

Am I flogging a dead horse with this idea or is there something else I can try?

here is my item command code:

```
   protected void showSubCat_itemCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {

            using (var db = new ps.data.Entities1())
            {

                int id = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
                var subCats = (from sc in db.vwSubCategories
                               where sc.primaryCategoryID == id
                               select sc).ToList();

                SubCategories.DataSource = subCats;
                SubCategories.DataBind();
                currentCatChosen.Value = id.ToString();
            }
     }
```

Comment: You were probably on the right line with your investigation into the ajax solution, otherwise you're stuck with the postback which will undo your js changes. Another option is to use the js to populate some hidden values to record the state of the changed controls. These will be posted to the server on postback, and you can then read and act upon these changes before you display the page again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I tried to run a bit of jquery from code behind using registerstartupscript, but it ran before the DOM had completed and my images reverted back to 1.0 opacity*

IMO, this is the correct appropach to take. As far as the images reverting... did you try wrapping the code in `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: thankyou - I wrapped in document ready and I was nearly there. The only issue I had was that by the point the DOM had loaded, it had obviously forgotten the id of the control that had been clicked. I had to frig the itemcommand to take 2 values (as it was already being used) and then split in code behind & feed the itemindex to the jquery to rediscover the id of the button.